# What is 7-Zip’s command-line argument to create a self extracting archive?

Tags: command-line, zip, 7-zip, batch-file

I looked everywhere and couldn't find a straight answer from anyone.

If I want to package the contents of C:\Temp  into a file called Temp.exe (in 7z format) that is self-extracting, how do I do it in a batch file?

This doesn't work:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -mx5 -sfx 7z.sfx directoryname archive.exe -mmt
```

What I get from that is a self extracting archive called 7z.sfx .  Can't figure this out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out after fiddling with it:

```
:: zip
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a archive.exe -mmt -mx5 -sfx dirname
pause
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue you were having is that 7-zip doesn't like spaces in the arguments.  So what you wanted was something more like:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a archive.exe -mmt -mx5 -sfx7z.sfx dirname
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -mx5 -sfx archive.exe directoryname -mmt
```

(PS: Add `Program Files\7-zip` to your `PATH` environment variable, there by you can access the file directly as `7z.exe` rather than `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"`)

Comment: it needs to work on anyones system.  since 7-zip installs to that directory by default on all windows systems, this makes the script much more likely to run on someone elses system.

Comment: Then use one of the following environment variables:
ProgramFiles=
ProgramFiles(x86)

Answer (score 1):

Keep it basic. The manual says the default:

- type is `7z`
- compression method is `5` ( use `0` for *copy* and `9` for *ultra*)
- (`-mmt` is for multi-threading and might be antiquated as the manual lacks its definition.)

So this give the basic answer as:

```
7z a -sfx archive.exe dir
```

Answer (score 0):

With 7-zip there is command line version available called 7z.exe you can download it from 7-zip's website.  To create a self extracting installer use the -sfx flag followed by a number for the compression amount.

Comment: didn't work. see question revision.

Comment: looks like you just had to move a few things around.  I'm glad it worked out for you.